# Connect to Windows Server 2012 VPN using L2TP randomly fails

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I have multiple computers running Windows 11 Pro. All computers have the same problem. I'm trying to connect to a remote L2TP/IPSEC VPN with a pre-shared key.

Client side: I have two vpn entries. One with the direct ip address, and another with the dyndns url (because the remote server has a dynamic IP).

The strange thing is that the connection works randomly (on all client pc's). Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I can't find any logic. Sometimes it's the direct ip address that works, sometimes the dyndns. I checked the dyndns ip and it's correct.

On the server side the followings port are open (NATed):
500 UDP + 4500 UDP

Client option: Encryption is option accepting EAP-MSCHAPv2 / firewall disabled / services “IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules” and “IPsec Policy Agent” already restarted. DWORD Registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent ==> AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule is set to 2

Client error: The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during the initial negotiations with the remote computers.

Client Logs: Error 789

Any Idea ? My first guess goes to the server (maybe something incorrectly configured?).

Comment: Windows Sever 2012 is out of support.